# Why am I getting a delayed result trying to load information into Modal with Apollo with useLazyQuery

Tags: reactjs, apollo

Trying to load information to fill a Modal with information from MongoDB table, using Apollo and React.

The query works fine, gives me the correct information, but upon trying to render it, I get the previous queries results, which makes zero sense to me. Following the sequence, there should be no way that information is even still available.

The chain starts at a button, with an onClick listener calling a handleOpen() function ->

```
// BAND INFO MODAL
  const [getBand, { error: err, loading: load, data: response }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY_NAME);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  function handleOpen(params) {
    getBand({ variables: { name: params } });
    setInfo(response?.userName);
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
    setInfo("");
  }
```

I've tried many different iterations, from calling setInfo() the same time as handleOpen() in the onClick() event, to even setting a timeout so there's no way the response is slow. If I visit the page for the first time and click to open the modal, I'm presented with blank fields, then the next click loads the information from the previous attempt and carries on in that fashion.

I hope I've made the point clear, apologies if this seems silly or obvious, I've spent a good 3 hours and exhausted the options I can think of.